# What exactly does Math.floor do?

Tags: javascript, math, random

I understand that `Math.floor` rounds to closest integer, for example

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(0.9);
}
```

will output `1`.

But I fail to understand why

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
}
```

outputs `1`

Thanks.

Comment: It does not round to the closest integer. It removes any fractional portion of a floating point number; effectively it always rounds towards zero. `Math.floor(1.9999999)` is `1`. `Math.floor(0.9)` is `0`, not `1`; have you tried it in your browser's developer console?

Comment: Just [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Comment: If you are already downvoting, please be kind to explain why..

Comment: Getting downvotes because none of the statements in question are correct and this is simple math if you read the manual for what Math.floor actually does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in fact this line of code outputs `0`:

```
 Math.floor(0.9);
```

`Math.floor` always rounds to the nearest whole number that is smaller than your input. You might confuse it with `Math.round`, that rounds to *nearest* whole number.

This is why this code always outputs `1` or `0`, since input never gets to `2` or bigger:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
```

There's actually three different rounding functions in JavaScript: `Math.floor`, its opposite `Math.ceil` and the "usual" `Math.round`.

These work like this:

```
Math.floor(0.1); // Outputs 0
Math.ceil(0.1); // Outputs 1
Math.round(0.1); // Outputs 0

Math.floor(0.9); // Outputs 0
Math.ceil(0.9); // Outputs 1
Math.round(0.9); // Outputs 1

Math.floor(0.5); // Outputs 0
Math.ceil(0.5); // Outputs 1
Math.round(0.5); // Outputs 1
```

Comment: Thanks mate, so Math.ceil(2.3) will output 3?

Comment: Thanks a lot, understood mate

Answer (score 2):

> The floor() method rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer,
>   and returns the result.
>
> If the passed argument is an integer, the value will not be rounded.

Answer (score 2):

0 <= [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) < 1

Math.floor(input) = max(x, where x is integer and x <= input)

Therefore, let's see the result

0 <= Math.random() < 1

2 * 0 <= 2 * Math.random() < 2 * 1

0 <= 2 * Math.random() < 2

As a result, Math.floor(2 * Math.random()) = {0; 1}

EDIT:

Math.floor rounds downwards.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, `floor()` always rounds *downward* to the integer, not to the *closest* integer.

In answer to the other part of your question, `random()` by default returns a number between 0 and 1. Thus, `floor(random())` will always return zero. `floor(random()*2)` will return 1 half the time (when `random()` gave a result .5 or higher, making it one or more after the `*2`) and 0 the other halve of the time (when `random()` gave a result lower than .5, so multiplying it by two is still less than one.).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = Math.floor(.9);
$("body").append(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```